# Material-UI Table select all per page pagination

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Is it possible to select items only on the current page / per page in the [`Table`](https://mui.com/components/tables/#custom-pagination-actions)?

https://codesandbox.io/s/ebnf3?file=/demo.js

Answer (score 2):

You can look at how the rows get sorted and filtered inside the `TableBody` below, just take the part where it filter to the `handleSelectAllClick` function:

```
<TableBody>
  {/* if you don't need to support IE11, you can replace the `stableSort` call with:
      rows.slice().sort(getComparator(order, orderBy)) */}
  {stableSort(rows, getComparator(order, orderBy))
    .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
    .map((row, index) => {
      return (...);
    }
```

```
const handleSelectAllClick = (event) => {
  if (event.target.checked) {
    const newSelecteds = stableSort(rows, getComparator(order, orderBy))
      .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
      .map((n) => n.name);

    setSelected(newSelecteds);
    return;
  }
  setSelected([]);
};
```

At this point, it's almost working except that you can't clear all the selection because the `Checkbox`'s state inside the table header depends on the number of rows selected, it can't be unselected because you only select the rows in 1 page, not all rows. You can fix it by taking control of the `Checkbox` and make it always change state between the 2 options (select/unselect):

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState(false);
```

```
<Checkbox
  color="primary"
  // indeterminate={numSelected > 0 && numSelected < rowCount}
  checked={value}
  onChange={(_, value) => {
    setValue(value);
    onSelectAllClick(_, value);
  }}
  inputProps={{
    "aria-label": "select all desserts"
  }}
/>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 0):

Editing the `handleSelectAllClick` to the following should work:

```js
 const handleSelectAllClick = (event) => {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      const newSelecteds = stableSort(rows, getComparator(order, orderBy))
      .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
      .map((n)=>n.name) 

      setSelected(newSelecteds);
      return;
    }
    setSelected([]);
  };
```